# Best method to delete an item from a dict

Tags: python

In Python there are at least two methods to delete an item from a dict using a key.

```
d = {"keyA": 123, "keyB": 456, "keyC": 789}

#remove via pop
d.pop("keyA")

#remove via del
del d["keyB"]
```

Both methods would remove the item from the dict.

I wonder what the difference between these methods is and in what kinds of situations I should use one or the other.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

- Use `d.pop` if you want to **capture the removed item**, like in `item = d.pop("keyA")`.
- Use `del` if you want to **delete an item from a dictionary**.
- If you want to delete, suppressing an error if the key isn't in the dictionary: `if thekey in thedict: del thedict[thekey]`

Comment: There's also the minor point that `.pop` will be slightly slower than the del since it'll translate to a function call rather than a primitive.

Comment: Thanks, I will use `del` when I just want to delete an item.

Comment: Is it possible to delete a key without raising error if the key doesn't exist?

Comment: @Tony, ``if thekey in thedict: del thedict[thekey]``

Comment: So, what is *better* (speed, readability) now for safe deleting: checking with `if` or calling `.pop(key, None)?` :)

Comment: I would expect checking with `if` to be slower, as it causes another dictionary lookup. An exception would be if the check fails most of the time.

Comment: It is Pythonic to "ask forgiveness rather than permission". So therefore, how about: `try: del d[key] except: pass`

Comment: @BuvinJ so much code for something simple... dictionary lookups are extremely fast. @neoascetic both ways are good, but "if x in d: del d[x]" seems to be faster: on a terminal, `import timeit` then do a `timeit.timeit(stmt="if 'two' in a: del a['two']", setup="a={'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}", number=1000000)` and `timeit.timeit(stmt="a.pop('two', None)", setup="a={'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}", number=1000000)`

Comment: @BuvinJ: better practice to explicitly catch only the `except KeyError`, never have a "naked `except`". But in this case, it's shorter, faster, clearer and self-contained to test membership first: `if thekey in thedict:`

Comment: @Tony, `d.pop("key", None) "` will delete the "key", return the "key" or None and won't raise any KeyError.

Comment: That kind of optimisation seems premature to me. I would stick with `pop` 99% of the time and use `del` only if we really don't need to check if the key exists.

Answer (score 22):

`pop` returns the value of deleted key.
Basically, `d.pop(key)` evaluates as `x = d[key]; del d[key]; return x`.

- Use `pop` when you need to know the value of deleted key
- Use `del` otherwise

Answer (score 13):

Most of the time, the most useful one actually is:

```
d.pop("keyC", None)
```

which removes the key from the dict, but **does not** raise a `KeyError` if it didn't exist.

The expression also conveniently returns the value under the key, or `None` if there wasn't one.

Comment: I love this one!

Answer (score 3):

I guess it comes down to if you need the removed item returned or not. `pop` returns the item removed, `del` does not.

Answer (score 1):

Using a very simple timer I tested the efficiency of these functions:

> ```
> def del_er(nums,adict):
>      for n in nums:
>         del adict[n]
> def pop_er(nums,adict):
>      for n in nums:
>         adict.pop(n)
> ```
>
> On my system, using 100,000 item dict and 75,000 randomly selected indices, del_er ran in about .330 seconds, pop_er ran in about .412 seconds.

Comment: i think there is a bug in your code, both functions use the same method

Comment: The code has been updated, but have the stats?  (Since the stats are significantly different, I assume they were run o the correct code...)