# How to remove multiple indexes from a list at the same time?

Tags: python, list

Say I have this list here:

```
list = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

How would I delete say indexes `2, 3, 4`, and `5` at the same time?

pop doesn't accept multiple values. How else do I do this?

Answer (score 409):

You need to do this in a loop, there is no built-in operation to remove a number of indexes at once.

Your example is actually a contiguous sequence of indexes, so you can do this:

```
del my_list[2:6]
```

which removes the slice starting at 2 and ending just before 6.

It isn't clear from your question whether in general you need to remove an arbitrary collection of indexes, or if it will always be a contiguous sequence.

If you have an arbitrary collection of indexes, then:

```
indexes = [2, 3, 5]
for index in sorted(indexes, reverse=True):
    del my_list[index]
```

Note that you need to delete them in reverse order so that you don't throw off the subsequent indexes.

Comment: +1 How would this differ if instead of `del my_list[index]` we used `my_list.pop(index)`? Would it matter? In terms of efficiency or semantics?

Comment: Please excuse my comment, I'm learning Python, but Python reindex the array while looping for delete ? Why if you loop in normal order it raise an undefined offset exception ?

Comment: @kitensei It does reindex, but because sorts the indexes in reverse order first, we're removing from the right-hand end of the list, so we're never reindexing an element before we delete it.

Comment: Looping over indices backwards. Genius! I was here dreaming up some ridiculous situation of decrementing indices as I went along, when this was so much more elegant!

Comment: although a thumbs-up for the reverse deletion order, i think this would be a problem with negative indexes.

Comment: @Levon I think the main difference is that [pop returns the value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5713303/5049813) that you remove. Since we don't need the values we're deleting, we should probably use `del` in this case, though both will work.

Comment: I was badly needed this approach `indexes = [2, 3, 5]
for index in sorted(indexes, reverse=True):
    del my_list[index]` Thank you so much.

Comment: Please note that this solution would produce incorrect results in case indices duplicating.

Comment: If your list has duplicates you should try using `set(indexes)` before as set naturally has no dupes. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7961390/10473393

Answer (score 82):

```
remove_indices = [1,2,3]
somelist = [i for j, i in enumerate(somelist) if j not in remove_indices]
```

Example:

```
In [9]: remove_indices = [1,2,3]

In [10]: somelist = range(10)

In [11]: somelist = [i for j, i in enumerate(somelist) if j not in remove_indices]

In [12]: somelist
Out[12]: [0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: As @C.Yduqoli points out below, this is the most efficient solution (we don't need to keep rebuilding the list), but you must convert `remove_indices` to a `set` first!

Comment: And the most elegant solution

Answer (score 39):

There wasn't much hint on performance for the different ways so I performed a test on removing 5000 items from 50000 in all 3 generally different approaches, and for me numpy was the winner (if you have elements that fit in numpy):

- 7.5 sec for the enumerated list comprehension [4.5 sec on another PC]
- 0.08 sec for deleting items in reverse order [0.017 (!) sec]
- 0.009 sec for numpy.delete [0.006 sec]

Here's the code I timed (in the third function conversion from/to list may be removed if working directly on numpy arrays is ok):

```
import time
import numpy as np
import random

def del_list_indexes(l, id_to_del):
    somelist = [i for j, i in enumerate(l) if j not in id_to_del]
    return somelist

def del_list_inplace(l, id_to_del):
    for i in sorted(id_to_del, reverse=True):
        del(l[i])

def del_list_numpy(l, id_to_del):
    arr = np.array(l, dtype='int32')
    return list(np.delete(arr, id_to_del))

l = range(50000)
random.shuffle(l)
remove_id = random.sample(range(len(l)), 5000) # 10% ==> 5000

# ...
```

Comment: `del_list_indexes` should be much faster if you convert `id_to_del` to a set first.

Comment: @C.Yduqoli The times I get **if using a `set` for `enumerate`** are: `enumerate` = 0.0041, `del` = 0.035, `numpy` = 0.0079, which has enumerate as the fastest as expected.

Answer (score 19):

If you can use [numpy](http://scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc#head-b7123bfe5a5e25fcbdd2ca4c3110e21a6fe8ea0b), then you can delete multiple indices:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> np.delete(a,(1,3,5))
array([0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

and if you use `np.r_` you can combine slices with individual indices:

```
>>> np.delete(a,(np.r_[0:5,7,9]))
array([5, 6, 8])
```

However, the deletion is not `in place`, so you have to assign to it.

Answer (score 17):

If they're contiguous, you can just do

```
x[2:6] = []
```

If you want to remove noncontiguous indexes, it's a little trickier.

```
x = [v for i,v in enumerate(x) if i not in frozenset((2,3,4,5))]
```

Comment: As a note, the reason you have to do it with an enumerate is because you can't delete on something you're iterating over, that would be bad.

Comment: @Trick Technically, that's only true if you're using a real iterator. If you use a simple int to maintain your position in the list, there are no problems, except that the index will skip if you delete something at a position lower than the current position.

Comment: Yea, which could skip out of bounds, generally not a good thing to do.

Answer (score 6):

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
lst = lst[0:2] + lst[6:]
```

This is a single step operation. It  does not use a loop and therefore executes fast. It uses list slicing.

Comment: You should include explanation for your code. In general, describing how and why certain commands or code solves a problem is more useful as it helps the OP and others to solve similar issues.

Comment: please review the edition and kindly instruct.

Comment: wondering why 1460 days and 23410 views , did not come up with this simple solution. thats kind of depressing.

Comment: I've edited your answer to improve grammar and to use `lst` for variable name as `list` is a Python data type. The reason why nobody suggested this as a solution is that this creates a new list object (based on the contents of the original) rather than actually modifying the original list object. Since the end result is similar, I'll upvote your answer. Welcome to [se].

Comment: What does [6:] do?

Comment: This answer needs to be further up. smh

Answer (score 2):

another option (in place, any combination of indices):

```
_marker = object()

for i in indices:
    my_list[i] = _marker  # marked for deletion

obj[:] = [v for v in my_list if v is not _marker]
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I have an answer.

First, peruse the elements of the list like so:

```
for x in range(len(yourlist)):
    print '%s: %s' % (x, yourlist[x])
```

Then, call this function with a list of ***the indexes*** of elements you want to pop.  It's robust enough that the order of the list doesn't matter.

```
def multipop(yourlist, itemstopop):
    result = []
    itemstopop.sort()
    itemstopop = itemstopop[::-1]
    for x in itemstopop:
        result.append(yourlist.pop(x))
    return result
```

As a bonus, result should only contain elements you wanted to remove.

> In [73]: mylist = ['a','b','c','d','charles']
>
> In [76]: for x in range(len(mylist)):
>
> ```
>       mylist[x])
> ```
>
> ....:
>
> 0: a
>
> 1: b
>
> 2: c
>
> 3: d
>
> 4: charles
>
> ...
>
> In [77]: multipop(mylist, [0, 2, 4])
>
> Out[77]: ['charles', 'c', 'a']
>
> ...
>
> In [78]: mylist
>
> Out[78]: ['b', 'd']