# list assignment index out of range when trying to remove an element by index

Tags: python, list, indexing, delete-operator, del

I have the following list in Python:

```
x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,'inf'],[6,7],['nan',10]]
```

I also have the following index list:

```
idx = [2,4]
```

I'm trying to remove the elements from the list x corresponding to the index values in `idx`. For that, I did the following:

```
for i in idx:
    del x[i]
```

I however got the following error:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Either use a list comprehension or iterate in reverse by index and delete.

Comment: Alternative dupe: [How to remove multiple indexes from a list at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303225/how-to-remove-multiple-indexes-from-a-list-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting the index 2, then the index 4. The index 4 is the last item. As you are deleting the index 2, the last index becomes the index 3. So accessing the index 4 causes an error.

You might want to delete the indexes in reverse to avoid this.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Dunno if you downvoted, but he was calling the indexes, and not the elements.