# Python deleting from a dictionary using list comprehensions

Tags: python

I'm trying to be a good pythonista and use list comprehensions where possible...

Why doesn't this work?

```
[del my_dict[r] for r in to_remove]
```

The goal is to remove the entries in the list `to_remove` from my dict object `my_dict`
This:

```
for r in to_remove:
  del my_dict[r]
```

works fine but I am trying to do it with list comprehensions

Comment: List comprehension is used to create a new list from an old list, potentially checking a condition. For your usage you should use loops.

Comment: @andy boot, and for all pythonista's sake, read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a list comprehensions for side effects, it's not pythonic.

A simple for loop should be used instead.

Answer (score 11):

Because `del X` is a statement that is not meant to be used like that. It is syntactically incorrect.

Just:

```
for r in to_remove:
    del my_dict[r]
```

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer, because it mentions the real reason

Answer (score 5):

1. You're not gaining anything from the list comprehension here, because you're not after a new list.
2. del isn't a function, so you can't invoke it as part of a list comprehension.

Basically, just iterate over the list instead:

```
for r in to_remove:
    del my_dict[r]
```

Answer (score 1):

You COULD do:

```
[my_dict.pop(r) for r in to_remove]
```

`.pop` returns the value of the deleted key tho and it would be a tiny bit slower than `del` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713218/best-method-to-delete-an-item-from-a-dict)) and not the most "pythonic" way to do this. So you probably shouldn't as others have advised.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this, but I'd listen to jamylak. And of course this is returning a *new* list, not removing from `my_dict`

```
my_dict = [x for x in my_dict if x not in to_remove]
```

Comment: This could be also done via sets, e.g. `set(my_dict.keys()).difference(to_remove)`

Comment: I'm just giving the OP an option to look at. I explicitly mentioned it's not a good way to do it, and the question was in regard to _list comprehension_. Thanks for the `set` option though, I've never used the `difference` function before.

Comment: Totally agree, just commented in case you haven't used sets in such a manner :)