# What is a better way to remove key from dict in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, dictionary

I've found 2 ways of doing it:

```
del dict[key]
```

vs

```
dict.pop(key)
```

Which one is better and why, or maybe there's more?

Comment: or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713218/best-method-to-delete-an-item-from-a-dict; the other one was about lists

Answer (score 1):

del is generally faster than pop().

Have a look at this discussion [Best way to remove an item from a Python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447494/best-way-to-remove-an-item-from-a-python-dictionary)