# Merging two dic in python3 using Unpacking Generalisations in Python3.5

Tags: python, python-3.5, argument-unpacking

There are two dictionaries as follow which I want to merge them, my point is to select those keys that I am interested in, for example I am interested in all the keys except county. Solution I 've used is using `del` function after creating your new dictionary, however I am sure there are more ways that are more efficient to my solution. How can I solve this problem without del function using **UNPACKING ARGUMENT**.

```
    >>> d1 =  {'avgUserperDay': '12', 'avgPurchaseperDay': '1', 'country': 'Japan'}
    >>> d2 = {'tUser': 1, 'tPurchase': 0, 'country': 'Japan'}
    >>> d ={**d1,**d2}
    >>>{'tUser': 1, 'tPurchase': 0, 'avgPurchaseperDay': '1', 'avgUserperDay': '12', 'country': 'Japan'}
    >>> del d['country']
    >>> d
    {'tUser': 1, 'tPurchase': 0, 'avgPurchaseperDay': '1', 'avgUserperDay': '12'}
```

AFTER DISCUSSION,

This command works with 3.5.1,

```
>>> {**{k:v for k, v in chain(d1.items(), d2.items()) if k != 'country'}}
{'tUser': 1, 'tPurchase': 0, 'avgPurchaseperDay': '1', 'avgUserperDay': '12'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `del`, you can replace it by `.pop(key)`.
For example, using unpacking argument too:

```
d = dict(d1, **d2)
d.pop("country")
```

Notice that `.pop` returns the value too (here "Japan").

Comment: what is its preference to del?

Comment: It is useful if you want to retrieve the value.  But it must be slower.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5713303/6919239

Answer (score 1):

why would you want to do it using argument unpacking?
just do:

```
from itertools import chain
d = {key:value for key, value in chain(d1.iteritems(), d2.iteritems())
     if key not in keys_to_ignore}
```

where keys_to_ignore is list/set/tuple of keys you want to ignore

Answer (score 1):

> How can I solve this problem without del function using UNPACKING ARGUMENT?

Yes, you can. But you should not. Ideal way should be:

```
d1.update(d2)   # values will be updated in d1 dict
del d1['country']
```

There no direct way to meet your conditions:

- create new `dict` using *argument unpacking*
- not using `del` to remove country.

But there are work around if this is what you want. For example using `itertools.chain()` with *dict comprehension* as:

```
{**{k:v for k, v in chain(d1.items(), d2.items()) if k != 'country'}}
```

*Note:* For those curios about how `{**dict1, **dict2}` even works. It is new syntax supported since from python 3.5+, proposed in [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/). Check: [What's New in Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations) document.

Since, **`{**dict1, **dict2}` is only supported in Python 3.5+**, for earlier version of Python, you can do (as mentioned by S. [De Melo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39875454/2063361)):

```
d = dict(d1, **d2)
d.pop("country")
```

OR without using `**` as:

```
{k, v for k, v in chain(d1.iteritems(), d2.iteritems()) if k != 'country'}
```

Comment: Does this work in Python 2?  The `{**{` is a syntax error in Python 3

Comment: It  is supported only in Python 3.5+. But since user has specified in the sample code that it is working. I edited question with the 3.5 tag

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri in python3 i've got SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh : Check [What's new in Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-448-additional-unpacking-generalizations)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I am using version 3.5.1, also in my question you can see i have used unpacking argument and it works.

Comment: thx, I have added the correct one in description, u should use as above with 3.5.1, u can't use iteritems here..

Comment: error with this command is  `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`, by the way thx for your explanations