# How to delete keys from multiple dictionaries in a list python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have the following sample data as a listobject in python.

```
[{'itemdef': 10541,
    'description': 'Dota 2 Just For Fun tournament. ', 
    'tournament_url': 'https://binarybeast.com/xDOTA21404228/', 
    'leagueid': 1212, 
    'name': 'Dota 2 Just For Fun'}, 
{'itemdef': 10742, 
    'description': 'The global Dota 2 league for everyone.', 
    'tournament_url': 'http://www.joindota.com/en/leagues/', 
    'leagueid': 1640, 
    'name': 'joinDOTA League Season 3'}]
```

How can i remove the description, tour_url from this list; or how can I only keep the name and leagueid keys. I have tried a variety of solutions, but it just doesnt seem to work.

2nd question: how can I filter this list? As in mysql:

```
select *
from table
where leagueid = 1212
```

Please treat me like a new person to python, because i really am.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In fact `list` does not have keys, `list` has indices, and `dictionary` has keys. In your case, you have a list of dictionaries, and what you need is to remove some keys (2 exactly: description and tournament_url) form each item (dictionary) of your list:

```
for item in my_list:  # my_list if the list that you have in your question
    del item['description']
    del item['tournament_url']
```

To retrieve an item from your above list with some criteria, you can do:

```
[item for item in my_list if your_condition_here]
```

**Example:**

```
>>> [item for item in my_list if item['itemdef'] == 10541]
[{'leagueid': 1212, 'itemdef': 10541, 'name': 'Dota 2 Just For Fun'}]
```

**Edit:**

To filter `my_list` items to retrieve only some keys, you can do:

```
keys_to_keep = ['itemdef', 'name']

res = [{ key: item[key] for key in keys_to_keep } for item in my_list]
print(res)
# Output: [{'itemdef': 10541, 'name': 'Dota 2 Just For Fun'}, {'itemdef': 10742, 'name': 'joinDOTA League Season 3'}]
```

Comment: is there a difference between `del` and `item.pop`?

Comment: Wait, so I have a list of dictionaries? Damn, thanks a lot. I have been stuck on this shit forever.

Comment: @rassar `item.pop('key')` will also return value of the key so it's used when we need to read and delete object.

Comment: @rassar this answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/5713303/4575071

Comment: @ettanany is there also a way to not remove it from the current list, but select which keys i want to keep, eg: i have a list with dictionaries that contain a variable amount of keys. `del item` wont do the trick here (or if you could perheps invert it. Can you help me out?

Comment: @Adam take a look at my edited answer, I added what you are looking for.

Comment: Im so thankful for your answer. Do the keys of `keys_to_keep` stay in that order? Or does it keep changing its position everytime i rerun the code?

Comment: `keys_to_keep` is just a list of keys that you want to retrieve, the order is not important.

Comment: Uhm, i meant the order of keys in `res` ofcourse, my bad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129586/discussion-between-ettanany-and-adam).

Answer (score 0):

For the first question:

```
for item in table:
    item.pop(tournament_url)
```

For the second question:

```
[item for item in table if item[leagueid] == 1212]
```

Comment: Can you explain how to use that second piece of code?

Comment: @Adam there are three equivalent variants to do this: http://pastebin.com/miyEgkVY

Answer (score -1):

So what you have there is a list of dictionaries.  To remove the `tournament_url` key from the dictionaries, we'll use a dictionary comprehension

```
my_list = [{k:v for k, v in d.items() if k != 'tournament_url'} for d in my_list]
```

Read more about comprehensions in the [official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: This will recreate the list and all of the dictionaries. It's easier and quicker to iterate over the list removing the keys that aren't needed.

Comment: print [{key: value for key, value in d[x].items() if key!='tournament_url' and key!='description'} for x in range(len(d))]