# How to move items between dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, blackjack, playing-cards

i'm working now on a BlackJack program, and i want to make a full deck of cards in one dictionary, like..

```py
"card" : points
```

```py
cards = {
"2S" : 2,
"2H" : 2,
"2D" : 2,
"2C" : 2,
"3S" : 3,
"3H" : 3,
"3D" : 3,
"3C" : 3
.
.
.
"JS" : 10,
"JH" : 10,
"JD" : 10,
"JC" : 10,
}
```

... and then with deal add random cards to other dictionaries (players or computer) and remove from main deck or just move to:

```py
player_cards = {}
computer_cards = {}
```

How can i move random items from `cards` dictionary to other dictionary? that after the deal, the cards will disappear from the main deck and appear for player and for computer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best method to delete an item from a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713218/best-method-to-delete-an-item-from-a-dict)

Comment: I have a gut feeling that you really want to maintain `cards` as a `random.shuffle()` list of potentially multiple decks rather than as a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
random_card = random.choice(list(cards))
player_cards[random_card] = cards[random_card]
```

Comment: That is potentially 1/2 of it. just need to include removing/decrementing `cards`

Comment: Note that if you want this to function like an actual deck of cards this method does allow for duplicates to be picked.

Comment: I would like the card to disappear from the general deck after move.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your question

I assume the values in the dictionary "cards" are the number of cards remaining for each face and value, but that does not make much sense since you have multiple 2 of spades (I suppose this means you use multiple decks? But that would mean it is possible to draw two 2 of spades consecutively).

If this is what you want, then

```
import random 
drawn=random.choice([k for k in cards for x in range(cards[k])])

#If it is the player's turn
player_cards[drawn]=1

#If it is the computer's turn
player_cards[drawn]=1
```

This code would run into problems if you draw the same card consecutively due to same index key. I would therefore argue the meaning of setting player_cards and computer_cards as dictionaries. If you want to allow drawing the same card, turning them into lists and simply appending drawn cards to them would be a lot easier.

**Edit:**

For the card to disappear from the general deck after being drawn to the player's/computer's deck,

```
cards[drawn]-=1
```

Comment: Everything what i need is to move a item from one dictionary to another. First plays computer, so 2 cards desapears from `cards` and move to `computer_cards`, next turn is player - he also take a 2 cards, so from `cards` desapears now next 2 cards, and move to `player_cards`

Comment: What I want to know is the meaning of the "cards" dictionary, because I see cards={"2S" : 2, "2H" : 2,...}. Does this mean there are two 2 of Spades and two 2 of hearts?

Comment: no, every of cards with value 2 means thats cards have 2 points, cards with "3" have 3 points, with "4" have 4 points ... "J" have 10, "Q" have 10 "K" have 10 and "Ace" have 1 or 11. In the BlackJack game to win a player must be as close as possible to 21 points with 2 or more cards. I think building a deck of cards in the dictionary is a good way to go because we have one full deck and good basics to future play cards projects :) I might be wrong?